# How do I change this implementation to use single synchronization block instead of multiple?

Tags: scala, synchronization, lazy-evaluation, memoization

I have Events in my system and a function that calculates value depending on events and last calculated value:

When I call this function I want this behaviour:

- If there are new events, it should calculate new value using events and last memoized value, and memoize the result
- If there are no new events, it should return last value memoized

Here is the implementation I came up with:

```
<!-- language: lang-scala -->
class EventBasedMemo[Value, Event](initialValue: => Value,
                                    buildValue: (Value, Event) => Value,
                                    nextEvent: Option[Event] = None) {

  lazy val memoValue: Value = 
    nextEvent.fold(initialValue)(event => buildValue(initialValue, event))

  def update(event: Event): EventBasedMemo[Value, Event] =
    new EventBasedMemo(memoValue, buildValue, Option(event))

}

type Value = Int
type Event = String
var callsCount = 0

var memo = new EventBasedMemo[Value, Event](0, (value, event) => {
  callsCount += 1
  println(s"$callsCount $event")
  value + 1
})

memo = memo.update("A")
memo = memo.update("B")
memo = memo.update("C")

memo.memoValue //  1 A 2 B 3 C
memo.memoValue

memo = memo.update("D")

memo.memoValue // 4 D
```

This works fine. But the problem is that `lazy val` uses synchronization under the hood so there are multiple nested synchronizations happening for calculations, which is bad.

How do I change it so that it uses only one synchronization?

I want the solution to be immutable.

Answer (score 0):

Using manual memoization you can avoid synchronization blocks. But in multithreaded scenario cache could be recalculated several times. It is safe to recalculate it only if calculation does not have side effects (no print statements as in example).

```
class EventBasedMemo[Value, Event](initialValue: => Value,
                                   buildValue: (Value, Event) => Value,
                                   nextEvent: Option[Event] = None) {

  var cache: Option[Value] = None

  def memoValue(): Value = {
    cache match {
      case None =>
        cache = Some(nextEvent.fold(initialValue)(event => buildValue(initialValue, event)))
        cache.get
      case Some(value) => value
    }
  }

  def update(event: Event): EventBasedMemo[Value, Event] =
    new EventBasedMemo(memoValue, buildValue, Option(event))

}
```

If you really want to have lazy value with fast synchronization then take a look at read/write locks like [ReentrantReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html). Next code is just demonstration, not sure it works properly in multithreaded environment.

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock

class EventBasedMemo[Value, Event](initialValue: => Value,
                                   buildValue: (Value, Event) => Value,
                                   nextEvent: Option[Event] = None,
                                   lock:ReentrantReadWriteLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock()) {

  var cache: Option[Value] = None

  def memoValue(): Value = {
    lock.readLock().lock()
    val result = cache match {
      case None =>
        lock.readLock().unlock()
        lock.writeLock().lock()
        cache = Some(nextEvent.fold(initialValue)(event => buildValue(initialValue, event)))
        lock.writeLock().unlock()
        lock.readLock().lock()
        cache.get
      case Some(value) => value
    }
    lock.readLock().unlock()
    result
  }

  def update(event: Event): EventBasedMemo[Value, Event] =
    new EventBasedMemo(memoValue, buildValue, Option(event), lock)

}
```